# Get the list of recently updated columns in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using an SQL query, I would like to get the list of columns (corresponding to multiple tables) which are recently updated with INSERT/UPDATE (with in 10 minutes) on the PostgreSQL database!

I have tried using the option `information_schema.columns` but there is no information like `updated_time` for the columns. Happy to get any insights on this!

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "recently updated" so you mean DML (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`) or DDL (`ALTER TABLE`)?

Comment: @richyen DML only. Updating the question as well.. (INSERT / UPDATE)

Comment: I would say to create a rule on that table with last_updated column

Comment: Perhaps better asked on sister site: http://DBA.StackExchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This sort of information is not available in PostgresSQL. You would have to collect it yourself using triggers on the tables, but that would incur a performance penalty.